# First jQuery plugin- How can I save associatedelement data in a proper fashion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Well, this is not my first jQuery plugin but the first I think others would benefit from. So for me its the first time to make sure every possible application works as predicted.

My plugin handles modal less overlays and therefore has to save the overlay visibility in cookies.

At first I thought ok, I need one cookie to store the visibilitie. Of course this won't work as multiple elements can be overlays and therefore have different states.

The only solution I can think at this moment is, to *normalize* the used jQuery selector and use it as cookie path which in my opinion is no proper solution.

**Additional resources**
[Plugin Demo](http://mloverlay.mythli.net)
[Plugin documentation and full source code](https://github.com/Mythli/jquery.mloverlay)

**How can I save associatedelement data in a proper fashion?**

Edit:

```
$.cookie(PLUGIN_IDENTIFIER+'IsVisible', settings._isVisible);    
var isOverlayVisible = $.cookie(PLUGIN_IDENTIFIER+'IsVisible');
```

Comment: It would be great if you could add the relevant parts of your source code to your question

Comment: I don't understand why you're using cookies.

Comment: @Mathletics I use cookies to save the overlay visibility.

Comment: Right; what I mean is that I don't understand why you are using cookies instead of storing data in the DOM. Does the visibility information need to persist between pages?

Comment: Yes I wanted the visibility information to persist betweeen pages. But I now thought better of it as it was only "nice to have" and it seems to me that there is no "proper" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the id's with value in a JavaScript Object and then [`stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) / [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it with [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON):

```
// set;
$.cookie(PLUGIN_IDENTIFIER, JSON.stringify({ id1: true, id2: false }));

// get;
var obj = JSON.parse($.cookie(PLUGIN_IDENTIFIER));
```

Or use [[Session|Local|Global]Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage)...